# Rotating camera fails along one axis

Tags: 3d, matrix, c++11

Edit: I have solved this specific problem but created a new one with a fairly similar basic description. After the camera is rotated a number of times, then it begins to roll when it shouldn't. I have yaw and pitch bound to the mouse so I know that 0 is passed in for roll. The trouble is, I don't actually have any algorithmic way to even know whether or not this is happening, let alone correct the problem.

This is my existing code:

```
D3DXMATRIX CameraRotationMatrix;
D3DXVECTOR3 CameraPosition;
//D3DXVECTOR3 CameraRotation;

inline D3DXMATRIX GetRotationMatrix() {
    return CameraRotationMatrix;
}
inline void TranslateCamera(float x, float y, float z) {
    D3DXVECTOR3 rvec, vec(x, y, z);
    #pragma warning(disable : 4238)
    D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&rvec, &vec, &GetRotationMatrix());
    #pragma warning(default : 4238)
    CameraPosition += rvec;
    RecomputeVPMatrix();
}
inline void RotateCamera(float x, float y, float z) {
    D3DXVECTOR3 RotationRequested(x, y, z);
    D3DXVECTOR3 XAxis, YAxis, ZAxis;
    D3DXMATRIX rotationx, rotationy, rotationz;
    XAxis = D3DXVECTOR3(1, 0, 0);
    YAxis = D3DXVECTOR3(0, 1, 0);
    ZAxis = D3DXVECTOR3(0, 0, 1);

    #pragma warning(disable : 4238)
    D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&XAxis, &XAxis, &GetRotationMatrix());
    D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&YAxis, &YAxis, &GetRotationMatrix());
    D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&ZAxis, &ZAxis, &GetRotationMatrix());
    #pragma warning(default : 4238)
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&rotationx);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&rotationy);
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&rotationz);
    D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&rotationx, &XAxis, RotationRequested.x);
    D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&rotationy, &YAxis, RotationRequested.y);
    D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&rotationz, &ZAxis, RotationRequested.z);
    CameraRotationMatrix *= rotationx;
    CameraRotationMatrix *= rotationy;
    CameraRotationMatrix *= rotationz;
    RecomputeVPMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have done a lot of rotations using euler angles you may have got yourself into a gimbal lock.

[Wikipedia page on Gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)

Comment: I thought that Gimbal Lock reduced the available rotations, not changed them. Plus, I used Quaternions.

Comment: Ah, didn't realise you were using quaternions. Perhaps if you post a code snippet the problem would be clearer. Though you have probably solved it yourself by now.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you composing your rotations? If you just need yaw and pitch, it's easy to avoid unwanted rotations by combining the rotations from different sides.

For example, if you have a new mouse input that gives you a `pitch_diff` and a `yaw_diff` quaternion, you could do: `my_rotation = yaw_diff * my_rotation * pitch_diff`. That way, the "left half" of `my_rotation` will always be a yaw, and the "right half" will always be pitch. And you never get a roll component!

Comment: I take in an angle in radians from the mouse, transform the X, Y, Z axis to the existing camera axis with the existing camera rotation, then rotate around them by the angle given (transformed), then multiply them with the existing rotation.

Comment: That's why you get a roll component then - doing yaw-pitch-yaw rotations usually gives you tha. If you have yaw deltas `yN` and pitch deltas `pN`, you want a rotation that looks like this: `y1*y2*...*yN*p1*p2...*pN`, not `y1*p1*y2*p2*...*yN*pN`. Basically you wanna do yaw w.r.t. to the global coordinate system and pitch w.r.t to your camera's.